# Trying to get openGL 4 to work with amd card

Tags: 14.04, ati, opengl

I cant find anything that works to get the proprietary drivers for my AMD Radeon card. (I'm trying to play Metro 2033, but keep getting the error saying I need OpenGL 4.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

Answer (score 0):

Version of OpenGL also **depends on your GPU model**.

To see the supported version of OpenGL you should run from terminal:

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

For example my Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7600G] returns the following:

```
OpenGL version string: 4.4.13374 Compatibility Profile Context 15.20.1013
```

So proprietary fglrx driver supports OpenGL 4+.

Also you may see some details on OpenGL support in Wiki [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#OpenGL_4.3).